# What is the dice result probability curve of 4d6kh3r1, but with an exception rule?

Tags: probability, dice

So the equation is four 6-sided dice, keep the highest three results of the four results, and reroll any ones rolled. However the exception comes in where the reroll won't happen if there are already three results higher than a one, so only if there are two 1s rolled.

I am not certain if this is the right stackexchange for this question, but i can't find any auto statistic calculators online that can apply this exception. Anyone's know what the average and deviation would be?

An example below:

(4, 2, 4, 1) = 10 -> the 1 is dropped and not rerolled because there are 3 results higher than 1

(5, 2, 2, 4) = 11 -> one of the 2s is dropped and no rerolls because a 1 was not rolled

(1, 2, 2, 1, [1, 6]) = 10 -> two 1s were rolled and got rerolled into a 1 and 6, the new 1 is not rolled because you now have 3 results higher than 1.

Comment: Please give several examples of such sequences, some of which are OK and others not OK [with explanations]. To me it isn't clear what the allowable sequences are. Also do you stop when arriving at a non-OK sequence occurs and keep what occurred so far, or do you discard any sequence which is non-OK entirely [and disregard it when computing expected value or variance].

Comment: @coffeemath edited a few examples, is that enough?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, 4d6kh3r1 is the same as 4d5kh3 + 3. That simplifies solving the recursive rerolling formula's distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be [expressed using my Icepool library](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/icecup.html?c=GYJw9gtgBAlgxgUwA5jAG1hFIAuUAmANFAEoLhpoBQV+CwUI56aA+mAHYIDOrMwrCAFc0OGEjQIAFBTQBKAFxUoKqByER2XblAC8jFgDo4YIRxxSAjHOWr+ajVp5QAPPstLVXqAGIoAOTA8BA5TAHMACyhOZxwwKBwQGDCw8kZmSkNbb3ScIRAOA0ps31IMjBwIhGjtLK8mWQR8PQIpADY5QxR0KXVNGO5OhAAPJABDDnwpGy8-MggwADdqyuqxyhrnUxwTCBX4pCZl8ygJ2A5gGA4YHGq0VCQ61T8Glmn02R1VqHuAdx48NtdtUAEYATwI9DGIhwTxUr0oTRaCMk+EMKOmJTm5VOHAhTAgYyuVzCmx0UnsYyQhzAhxgY1unRKKKR+hZaO4QhBMnKTl4-EEMPEkhmqjoDDCDKqIB5jXw7CEO0gCEUJS86zYn2RLAA2n0+QoALpQADUHxYTQVSr2atUTDyBQSQgk0m4YFwTSkGtYnzkovhCAdhXZhk53MlqxANioNJQ3FZ5sofL4AmEomF0isxEs2ezftDXKkaDGEBB+DGUGGCignIgUmGOo8hr9NDp5ikwAA5ABZBATasAb1jYHjaL2E2mAF8oABlAAig+Ho9DOAm5ZA8roi3pYk4U870e2SEVUiXTWIACIz-gLzYjyeph1DABrBDIVgRZJVbgWAAsxAAZjkS9f3wNpnwiADbyoe8LEfTpX3fT9IgBKQAFZAOAqALzQsCIKguQgA) as such:

```
from icepool import d, Reroll

def reroll_ones_if_multiple(roll):
    num_ones = roll.count(1)
    if num_ones <= 1:
        # Not enough ones to trigger reroll.
        return roll
    # Reroll the ones.
    rerolled = d(6).pool(num_ones).expand()
    # Remove the all ones outcome to prevent an infinite loop.
    # reroll() rerolls the lowest outcome by default.
    rerolled = rerolled.reroll()
    # Reroll any remaining ones (if appropriate).
    rerolled = rerolled.sub(reroll_ones_if_multiple)
    def gather(rerolled_outcome):
        all_rolls = roll[num_ones:] + rerolled_outcome
        return tuple(sorted(all_rolls))
    return rerolled.sub(gather)

proposed = reroll_ones_if_multiple((1, 1, 1, 1)).sub(lambda x: sum(x[1:]))

print(f'Mean: {proposed.mean()} SD: {proposed.standard_deviation()}')

output(proposed, "proposed")
output(d(6).keep_highest(4, 3), "4d6kh3")
output(d(6).keep_highest(5, 3), "5d6kh3")
```

Result:

Mean: 12.824477686989315 SD: 2.5054380002701975

Die with denominator 9744875

| Outcome | Quantity | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 0.000000% |
| 4 | 0 | 0.000000% |
| 5 | 0 | 0.000000% |
| 6 | 42091 | 0.431930% |
| 7 | 135240 | 1.387806% |
| 8 | 288414 | 2.959648% |
| 9 | 519547 | 5.331490% |
| 10 | 837606 | 8.595349% |
| 11 | 1116318 | 11.455437% |
| 12 | 1337749 | 13.727718% |
| 13 | 1439130 | 14.768070% |
| 14 | 1393560 | 14.300440% |
| 15 | 1147237 | 11.772722% |
| 16 | 826434 | 8.480704% |
| 17 | 475986 | 4.884475% |
| 18 | 185563 | 1.904211% |